# Div class name with $count; in wordpress loop

Tags: css, wordpress, loops

I need to add a $count; after classname to a post div inside a loop. Example of meaning:  - so classes for posts will be mypost1, mypost2...

I go this working fine, but I don't know how to add $count after classname.

```
<?php $count = 0; if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++; ?>
<div class="mypost">...</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply `echo` your variable in the appropriate place:

```
<?php $count = 0; if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++; ?>
<div class="mypost<?php echo $count; ?>">...</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: @MichalBěhal No worries.